# Scala - How to get a wrapped method's name?

Tags: scala, reflection, wrapper

I have the following wrapper:

```
def ProtectedAction[T](f: => T)(implicit user: User): T = {
    if(isAuthorized()) f
    else { 
        Logger.warn(user.login + "Had access denied to" + methodsName)
        throw new NotAuthorizedException("You do not have permission to execute this operation.")
    }
}
```

I'd like to get the simpleName of the method wich is being held by **f**. How can I do that?

Comment: `f` doesn't necessarily have a name, it could be anonymous

Comment: Right.. but what if it does?

Comment: `f` will never have a name, see the linked duplicate

Comment: got it. So if I really need to know its name, I should somehow pass it forward .